# Mongoose - Manipulating the find's result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, eloquent

I would like to manipulate the object that's going to be returned by `find`, `findOne` and all the finds.

I've worked with Laravel and there is a great solution for this called Eloquent Mutators. I want to achieve the same result in Mongoose.

For example, my schema called `User` has a `firstname`, `lastname` and an `email` property defined in the Mongoose Schema. But when I perform a find (or any other find-related query) query, I want my result object to be returned like only a `fullname` and `email` property, despite of my Mongoose Schema has a pretty different schema.

How could I achieve this?

---

As per the answers below, I edited my Model as the following:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

User.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            email: 1,
            fullName: {
                $concat: ["$firstname", " - ", "$lastname"]
            }
        }
    },
], function (error, result) {
    console.log({ error, result })
})
```

At the last line the `console.log` prints out the perfect output I am looking for.

However the `find` method is returning the same result as before.

```
User.find().then(result => {
    console.log({result})
})
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `Find` and `Aggregate` are different.

Comment: In the meantime I realized it. Then how would it solve my problem? `Aggregate` is not meant to manipulate the result of `find`, `findOne`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by following:-
1) `$project` fullName by assigning the value from firstName and lastName.
2) Use `$addToSet` and add field fullName.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I edited the question, can you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use the `option` parameter with the fields you want on your result

from the doc:
`Adventure.findOne({ type: 'iphone' }, 'name', function (err, adventure) {});`

or you can use the select chain function
`Adventure.find({}).select('name age')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$concat` in `$project`

```
db.getCollection('User').aggregate(
   [
      { $project: { 
          email : 1,
          fullName: { $concat: [ "$firstname", " - ", "$lastname" ] } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I edited the question, can you please have a look?